# looking for a word meaning "crouching carriage"

Tags: meaning

When some one always has a crouching posture what is it called? For example a beggar walks towards you and his body is kind of bent all the time.

Comment: how about crawler?

Comment: **Crooked.** Bent or twisted out of shape or out of place.

Comment: Hunchback (see any text regarding Richard III or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hunchback_of_Notre-Dame)

Answer (score 2):

Try: *Deformed* or *Physically [deformed](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/deform)*

> Distort the shape or form of; make misshapen:
>   '*he was physically deformed by a rare bone disease*'

or

[Hunch](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hunch)

> A humped position or thing:

Answer (score 0):

> **slouch**
>
> a drooping or bending forward of the head and shoulders
>
> an awkward,  drooping posture or carriage

[Source](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/slouch?s=ts)

You can also find related synonyms for this word [here](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/slouch?s=t).